# Dropdown_SelectedIndexchange event fires for all rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I have gridview which contains dropdown list in each row. The drop down list has selected index change event. Now when I change the value in drop down in any row of a grid, it fires selected index change event for all rows in gridview.
How to solve this issue?

Below is HTML mark up

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEditFields" runat="server" 
                        AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" OnRowDataBound="gvEditFields_RowDataBound" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectList" runat="server" Width="130px" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjectList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProjectList" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlProjectList" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="EditGridSave"
                                        Text="Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false" Width="150px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTaskList" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlTaskList" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="EditGridSave"
                                        Text="Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskStatus" runat="server"  Width="100px"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTaskStatus" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlTaskStatus" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="EditGridSave"
                                        Text="Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="30" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code for row databound and selected index change event.

```
protected void gvEditFields_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SetEditFieldsGridRecords(e.Row);
        //DropDownList ddlProjectList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlProjectList");

    }
}

protected void ddlProjectList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DropDownList ddlProjectList = (DropDownList)sender;
   // GridViewRow Row = (GridViewRow)ddlProjectList.NamingContainer;
    GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)ddlProjectList.Parent.Parent;
    int i = selectedRow.RowIndex;
    DropDownList ddlTaskList = (DropDownList)selectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlTaskList");
    DropDownList ddlTaskStatus = (DropDownList)selectedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlTaskStatus");

    BindTasks(clsCheckDBNull.ToStr(ddlProjectList.SelectedValue), -1, ddlTaskList);
    BindStatus(clsCheckDBNull.ToInt(ddlTaskList.SelectedValue), "", ddlTaskStatus);

}
```

Below is the code for methods used

```
private void BindStatus(int intTaskId, string TaskStatus, DropDownList drpStatus)
{
    DataTable dt = clsProjectTaskStatuses.SelectAll(BTMSession.AccountID);
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    drpStatus.DataTextField = "str_PROJECT_TASK_STATUS_NAME";
    drpStatus.DataValueField = "int_PROJECT_TASK_STATUS_ID";
    drpStatus.DataSource = dv;
    drpStatus.DataBind();
    SiteUtility.BindTooltip(drpStatus);

    if (drpStatus.Items.Count >= 2 && TaskStatus.Trim() != "")
    {
        if (drpStatus.Items.FindByText(TaskStatus.ToString()) != null)
            drpStatus.SelectedIndex = drpStatus.Items.IndexOf(drpStatus.Items.FindByText(TaskStatus.ToString()));
    }
}
```

---

```
private void BindTasks(string ProjectNo, int intTaskid, DropDownList drpTasks)
{
    if (drpTasks.Items.Count >= 1)
        drpTasks.Items.Clear();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    clsImportFileTypeDAL objImportFileTypeDAL = new clsImportFileTypeDAL();
    ds = objImportFileTypeDAL.SelectTaskListByProjectNoUserIDForTimeImport(ProjectNo, clsCheckDBNull.ToInt(BTMSession.UserId));
    CommonHelper.DisposeOf(objImportFileTypeDAL);

    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        drpTasks.DataTextField = "str_TASK_SUMMERY";
        drpTasks.DataValueField = "int_task_id";
        drpTasks.DataSource = ds;
        drpTasks.DataBind();
    }

    drpTasks.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Task", "-1"));
    SiteUtility.BindTooltip(drpTasks);
    drpTasks.SelectedValue = "-1";

    if (drpTasks.Items.Count >= 2)
    {
        if (drpTasks.Items.FindByValue(intTaskid.ToString()) != null)
            drpTasks.SelectedIndex = drpTasks.Items.IndexOf(drpTasks.Items.FindByValue(intTaskid.ToString()));
    }
}
```

---

private void SetEditFieldsGridRecords(GridViewRow row)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)row.DataItem;

```
    DropDownList ddlProjectList = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlProjectList");
    BindProjects(clsCheckDBNull.ToStr(drv["str_PROJECT_NO"]), ddlProjectList);

    DropDownList ddlTaskList = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlTaskList");
    BindTasks(ddlProjectList.SelectedValue, clsCheckDBNull.ToInt(drv["int_TASK_NO"]), ddlTaskList);

    DropDownList ddlTaskStatus = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlTaskStatus");
    BindStatus(clsCheckDBNull.ToInt(ddlTaskList.SelectedValue), clsCheckDBNull.ToStr(drv["TaskStatus"]), ddlTaskStatus);

    BTMWeb.Calender.Calender txtWorkDate = (BTMWeb.Calender.Calender)row.FindControl("txtWorkDate");
    DropDownList drpStartHours = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drpStartHours");
    DropDownList drpStartMinutes = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drpStartMinutes");
    DropDownList drpEndHours = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drpEndHours");
    DropDownList drpEndMinutes = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("drpEndMinutes");
    TextBox txtDescription = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");

    int StartHours = clsCheckDBNull.ToDate(drv["StartTime"]).Hour;
    int StartMinutes = clsCheckDBNull.ToDate(drv["StartTime"]).Minute;
    int EndHours = clsCheckDBNull.ToDate(drv["EndTime"]).Hour;
    int EndMinutes = clsCheckDBNull.ToDate(drv["EndTime"]).Minute;

    txtWorkDate.DateValue = clsCheckDBNull.ToDate(drv["dt_WORKDATE"]);
    drpStartHours.SelectedValue = StartHours.ToString();
    drpStartMinutes.SelectedValue = StartMinutes.ToString();
    drpEndHours.SelectedValue = EndHours.ToString();
    drpEndMinutes.SelectedValue = EndMinutes.ToString();

    txtDescription.Text = clsCheckDBNull.ToStr(drv["str_Description"]);

}
```

For eg. if I have rows and if I change dropdown value in first row, the selected index change fires for both the rows.

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: How have you determined that it "fires selected index change event for all rows in gridview"? Anyway, what does that mean at all?

Comment: And please don't share *all* your code. Share a *brief* and *concise* snippet of, say, the markup with your dropdownlist, the piece of code where you hook up the event handler, and the event handler itself.

Comment: Please check the question. I have added code

Answer (score 0):

Just one or two improvement suggestions:

- Use the `NamingContainer` property to get the reference to the the `GridViewRow` instead of `Paret.Parent` which is inherently error-prone(e.g. in case you use a control in the `TemplateField` that is a container-control.

So instead of:

```
GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)ddlProjectList.Parent.Parent;
```

this

```
GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)ddlProjectList.NamingContainer;
```

- Related to this: always use `FindControl` on the `NamingContainer` of the control you want to find, that is the `GridViewRow` in this case, `TableCell` does not implement [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx).

So instead of:

```
DropDownList ddlTaskList = (DropDownList)selectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlTaskList");
```

this

```
DropDownList ddlTaskList = (DropDownList)selectedRow.FindControl("ddlTaskList");
```

This is simply less error-prone.

Side-note: it's not clear why you need a method like `CommonHelper.DisposeOf`.
I assume you'll find the core problem in `BindTasks` and `BindStatus`. Can you show them?

Comment: Can you please provide solution of this problem..?

Comment: @ChiragFanse: Have you seen the last sentence of my answer? Btw, why do you show `RowDataBound` without showing `SetEditFieldsGridRecords`?

Comment: ..Oh sorry.
Btw U have added all methods used in code. Please review once again

Comment: @ChiragFanse: Sorry, i've found no obvious reason. Is the event handler called twice or really for every row(if the `GridView` contains more rows). Is the event handler triggered in the same request or in the next postback? Are you databinding the GridView from page_load only if `!IsPostBack`?

Comment: Yes the event handler called twice and it is triggred on the same req. I kept break point on page load, at event entrance and at event exit. After page load, control goes to event entrance then event body and event exit. From event exit again it goes to event entrance. I am binding grid in !IsPostBack.